# Table height header support for iPhone 5, and 6/6+

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

I am trying to add header support for all the iPhones and this is what i have so far, but it does not work when i run it. What do I need to edit in my code in order for it to work.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    NSLog(@"iphone 6 plus support");

    if ([model isEqualToString:@"iPhone7,1"])



    if (section == self.objects.count) {
        return 0.0f;
    }
    return 54.0f;

}


NSLog(@"iphone 5");

if ([model isEqualToString:@"iPhone7,2"])

    if (section == self.objects.count) {
        return 0.0f;
    }
return 16.0f;
```

Comment: What part isn't working? The headers or detecting the device? Also don't recommend you use screen bounds to detect device, use something like `NSString *model = [RSDeviceInfo verboseModel];     if ([model isEqualToString:@"iPhone7,2"]) { return @"iPhone 6"; }`

Comment: It is not detecting the device, which doesn't let the header height to adjust for the device.

Answer (score 0):

I use a class with these methods in it to determine device type:

```
+ (BOOL)isIphone4S {
    if ([[self verboseModel] isEqualToString:@"iPhone4,1"])
        return YES;
    else
        return NO;
}

+ (BOOL)isIphone6Any {
    if ([[self verboseModel] containsString:@"iPhone7"])
        return YES;
    else
        return NO;
}

+ (BOOL)isIphone6Plus {
    if ([[self verboseModel] isEqualToString:@"iPhone7,1"])
        return YES;
    else
        return NO;
}

+ (BOOL)isIphone6 {
    if ([[self verboseModel] isEqualToString:@"iPhone7,2"])
        return YES;
    else
        return NO;
}

+ (NSString *) verboseModel{
    size_t size;
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0);
    char *machine = malloc(size);
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", machine, &size, NULL, 0);
    NSString *model = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:machine];
    free(machine);
    return model;
}

+ (NSString *) deviceModel{
    NSString *model = [RSDeviceInfo verboseModel];
    if ([model isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,1"])    return @"iPhone 1G";
    if ([model isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,2"])    return @"iPhone 3G";
    if ([model isEqualToString:@"iPhone2,1"])    return @"iPhone 3GS";
    if ([model isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,1"])    return @"iPhone 4";
    if ([model isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,3"])    return @"Verizon iPhone 4";
    if ([model isEqualToString:@"iPhone4,1"])    return @"iPhone 4S";
    if ([model isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,1"])    return @"iPhone 5 (GSM)";
    if ([model isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,2"])    return @"iPhone 5 (GSM+CDMA)";
    if ([model isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,3"])    return @"iPhone 5c (GSM)";
    if ([model isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,4"])    return @"iPhone 5c (GSM+CDMA)";
    if ([model isEqualToString:@"iPhone6,1"])    return @"iPhone 5s (GSM)";
    if ([model isEqualToString:@"iPhone6,2"])    return @"iPhone 5s (GSM+CDMA)";
    if ([model isEqualToString:@"iPhone7,2"])    return @"iPhone 6";
    if ([model isEqualToString:@"iPhone7,1"])    return @"iPhone 6 Plus";

    if ([model isEqualToString:@"iPod1,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 1G";
    if ([model isEqualToString:@"iPod2,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 2G";
    if ([model isEqualToString:@"iPod3,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 3G";
    if ([model isEqualToString:@"iPod4,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 4G";
    if ([model isEqualToString:@"iPod5,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 5G";

    if ([model isEqualToString:@"iPad1,1"])      return @"iPad";
    if ([model isEqualToString:@"iPad2,1"])      return @"iPad 2 (WiFi)";
    if ([model isEqualToString:@"iPad2,2"])      return @"iPad 2 (GSM)";
    if ([model isEqualToString:@"iPad2,3"])      return @"iPad 2 (CDMA)";
    if ([model isEqualToString:@"iPad2,4"])      return @"iPad 2 (WiFi)";
    if ([model isEqualToString:@"iPad2,5"])      return @"iPad Mini (WiFi)";
    if ([model isEqualToString:@"iPad2,6"])      return @"iPad Mini (GSM)";
    if ([model isEqualToString:@"iPad2,7"])      return @"iPad Mini (GSM+CDMA)";
    if ([model isEqualToString:@"iPad3,1"])      return @"iPad 3 (WiFi)";
    if ([model isEqualToString:@"iPad3,2"])      return @"iPad 3 (GSM+CDMA)";
    if ([model isEqualToString:@"iPad3,3"])      return @"iPad 3 (GSM)";
    if ([model isEqualToString:@"iPad3,4"])      return @"iPad 4 (WiFi)";
    if ([model isEqualToString:@"iPad3,5"])      return @"iPad 4 (GSM)";
    if ([model isEqualToString:@"iPad3,6"])      return @"iPad 4 (GSM+CDMA)";
    if ([model isEqualToString:@"iPad4,1"])      return @"iPad Air (WiFi)";
    if ([model isEqualToString:@"iPad4,2"])      return @"iPad Air (Cellular)";
    if ([model isEqualToString:@"iPad4,4"])      return @"iPad mini 2G (WiFi)";
    if ([model isEqualToString:@"iPad4,5"])      return @"iPad mini 2G (Cellular)";

    if ([model isEqualToString:@"i386"])         return @"Simulator";
    if ([model isEqualToString:@"x86_64"])       return @"Simulator";
    return model;
}
```

Comment: Ok, these methods are good, but how would i implement it into the code i have above.

Comment: Create a new class and toss them in, requiring `<sys/types.h>` and `<sys/sysctl.h>`.

Comment: So is this what it should look like?

Comment: Yeah... Well, if you're not familiar with how to create a new class, start by googling that and go from there ;)